# See? How fun this game is!

Tags: subject-verb-inversion, exclamations

I'm not a native speaker, and I need help with the proper usage of exclamatives in some contexts.

[Context1: John is playing a video game alone, and is enjoying it. He utters:]
1. How fun this game is!
2. Is this a fun game!

[Context2: John is playing a video game with Peter, and is trying to persuade him that the game is fun. John utters:]
3. See? How fun this game is!
4. See? Is this a fun game!

Are these sentences acceptable in these two contexts? (Basically the first context conveys surprise with no audience and the second one expects Peter to be impressed.)

Comment: At first blush, all the above uses appear to be "acceptable".  #1 is a little "odd", and #2 would normally be preceded by "Boy!" or some similar exclamation.  #3 would more likely be "See how much fun this game is?"  #4 would likely be "See!  Is this a fun game or what?"  One interesting aspect is that the word "fun" can be used several different ways.  In particular, both "how fun" and "how much fun" are valid.

Comment: Normally one would say "See how *much* fun this game is" rather than "See how fun this game is", but the use of "fun" that way in the second version is acceptable (and perhaps more colloquial) in informal speech.

Answer (score -1):

For number 2, you probably want:

> Is this ever a fun game!

And for number 3, you'd say:

> See how fun this game is?